# compile time vs run time

Tags: java, runtime, polymorphism, compile-time

After going through 2-3 hour to know, what is the difference between **compile-time and run-time**. Lastly, i came up with this.

*Memory allocated at runtime referred to run-time/dynamic binding and allocated at compile time referred to compile-time/static binding.*

and then i tried this example

```
class myclass {

    void here() {
        System.out.println("Here from myclass !!");
    }

    void here(int i) {
        System.out.println("Here !!" + i);
    }
}

class thisclass extends myclass {

    void here() {
        System.out.println("Here from thisclass !!");
    }
}

public class poly {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        myclass m= new myclass();
        myclass a= new thisclass();
        m.here();
        m.here(12);
        a.here();
        a.here(13);
    }
}
```

So, i also found that `myclass a= new thisclass();` is considered to be run-time binding. Since, `a` is the object of `myclass`, but suddenly compiler found that, class mis-matched. So, it will be dynamically bind the space of `thisclass` object.

So, till here, i got the things. But, i found that, another common answer was ***overloading refer to compile time and overriding refer to run-time***. I didn't get this point.

```
thisclass a= new thisclass();
a.here();
```

Is this also called to be run-time binding. ?? Please correct me, if wrote anything wrong here.

Comment: Feel free to add [tag:C#] or [tag:Java]. This isn't C++.

Comment: sorry for that.. it is java code

Comment: Memory (which is used for the program) is never really allocated at compile-time.

Comment: then why we say static binding(compile time) and dynamic binding(run-time) ??

Comment: Memory allocation does not have anything to do with static or dynamic binding.

Comment: ok.. but, when we use `new` keyword that means we are creating new object of that class and allocating the space. isn't?? so if we say dynamic binding,in this case `myclass a= new thisclass();` we are creating object of `thisclass` and binding with the `myclass`. which means space of `thisclass` object will be used.  isn't ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, memory allocation is not in this picture. There is no compile-time memory allocation.

The question conflates compile-time with static binding and run-time with dynamic binding.

Static binding *happens at* compile time; dynamic binding *happens at* runtime.

Now, when you write

```
myclass m= new thisclass();
m.here(18);
```

what happens at compile-time is the resolution of the method *signature*: you are calling `here(int)` and that choice is final. This is termed "static binding". What happens at runtime is method *dispatch*: the runtime chooses a `here(int)` implementation appropriate to the runtime type of the object referenced by `m`. There are two methods to choose from: `myclass.m(int)` and `thisclass.m(int)`, and the runtime chooses the latter in this particular example. This is termed "dynamic binding".

As to your question "is overriding compulsory for dynamic binding"... The Java Language Specification prescribes the rules on choosing the correct method to invoke at runtime. These rules imply a procedure known as "dynamic binding" for the general case. But if you are asking whether any specific process always happens at runtime, the story is different: an optimizing JIT compiler can see that there is only one method to choose from and output a "monomorphic call site" which hardcodes the single choice. Further, it can also *inline* the entire method into the caller, thereby removing even the call itself.

Comment: ok,, so my question is.. is this a valid point to say `overloading refer to compile time and overriding refer to run-time` rather than `overloading refer to compile time and overriding required for run-time` i mean, is overriding compulsory for dynamic binding ??

Comment: This is implied by my answer. The resolution of the exact method overload to use (it is defined by its **signature**) happens at compile-time. The resolution of the exact method override to call happens at runtime.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "is overriding compulsory for dynamic binding". With or without method overrides, the dynamic binding is there.

Comment: To me, "compile time" means everything and anything that happens during compilation, and "run time" means everything and anything that happens when the code is run. There are many areas in which some decisions are made at compile time, others at run time. What is the purpose of looking for trying to attach those terms to any on type of decision?

Comment: yes.. you got my point .. this is what, i wanted to clear my doubt. `With or without method overrides, the dynamic binding is there` . So, it is not necessary that, overriding is there for run-time binding. isn't ??

Comment: I think we still need to clarify what exactly you mean by "dynamic binding". The Java Language Specification prescribes the rules on choosing the correct method to invoke at runtime. These rules imply a procedure known as "dynamic binding" for the general case. But if you are asking whether any specific process always happens at runtime, the story is different: an optimizing JIT compiler can see that there is only one method to choose from and output a direct `call` instruction with a fixed function address.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
thisclass a= new thisclass();
a.here();
```

is not run-time binding as the compiler knows what here() method to call (the one from thisclass). But if you would say:

```
myclass a= new thisclass();
a.here();
```

then would be a run-time binding.

P.S.: your classes names should start with a capital letter.

Comment: if you go through my question, then this was my question.. but, how ??? since, i have also mentioned `overloading refer to compile time and overriding refer to run-time`. what about this point.??

Comment: There is a full, blow-by-blow account of method invocation, including what is done at compile time and what is done at run time, in the Java Language Specification, (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12)

Answer (score 0):

> But, i found that, another common answer was overloading refer to
>   compile time and overriding refer to run-time. I didn't get this
>   point.

Overloading means having multiple methods with different parameters in the same class. Which method is called is known at compile time, because the arguments are specified at this time.

Overriding means re-defining a method from parent-class in the subclass.

Comment: i knew this.. but my question was.. why we say `overloading refer to compile time and overriding refer to run-time`.since, `myclass m=new thisclass();` is the point where we say dynamic binding. is this really need overriding ?? can't we do this, when we didn't implemented the overriding concept??

Comment: It is called run-time binding since, for example, later in your code you could dynamically change the type of `m` with whatever subclass of `myclass`. Like this: `m = new AnotherSubClass()`.